# Is it possible for gcc/clang to link into executable while stripping all the debug info meanwhile?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have some huge libraries that are compiled with debug info; when linking them with some small object files I write, it still takes quite a lot of time and the generated executable contains a lot of debug information of the libraries.

So is there an option to tell gcc/clang to discard those debug information inside the library? Will it improve the link speed?

If there is no easy way, should I `strip` the libraries? I don't think I have the priviledge since the libraries are also used by my partners who need to use the library code for debugging purpose.

Comment: I'd just create a copy of the libraries, `strip` the `debug` information and link my `executable with the `strip`ped version.

Comment: Try adding `-Wl,-s` or plain `-s` to the link command. I doubt ignoring the debug info will make a significant difference though, unless we're talking about GBs of data.

Comment: @rubenvb - it will work, if the hardware is pretty old/slow and the libraries are huge. For example - I work on a specific hardware, the machine is slow (pentium 2x1.5Ghz, 2GB RAM, etc.) and I'm using a huge lib - without the stripped information, it's about 450MB, stripped - about 32MB. On this platform here, the difference between linking to both versions of the libs is very big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said in the comments, there's two ways out:

1. Keep a local copy of said libraries, stripped of debug info.
2. Link with `-Wl,-s` or `-s`, which makes the linker output a stripped executable.